# Как сделать чтобы выпадающее меню при адаптации проталкивало "соседей родителя"?

Tags: css, css3, sass, scss

```css
* {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
a {text-decoration: none;}
ul {list-style: none;}

.navbar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;

    position: absolute;
}

/*nav*/

.nav .nav-link-container {
    background: #202020;

    padding: 15px;

    position: relative;
}

.nav .nav-link-container:hover {
    background: #999999;
}

.nav .nav-link-container:hover .dropdown-nav {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

/*dropdown-nav*/

.dropdown-nav {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;

    position: absolute;

    top: -9999px;
}

.dropdown-nav .dropdown-link-container {
    background: #202020;

    padding: 15px;
}

.dropdown-nav .dropdown-link-container:hover {
    background: #999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-link-container"><a href="#">parent link 1</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link-container">
            <a href="#">parent link 2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-nav">
                <li class="dropdown-link-container"><a href="#">child link 1</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-link-container"><a href="#">child link 2</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-link-container"><a href="#">child link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link-container"><a href="#">parent link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Сейчас оно открывается с правой стороны, а мне нужно чтобы под своим родителем и при этом проталкивало вниз соседей родителя. Думал что изменив координаты появления и установив родителю высоту сто процентов получится достичь желаемого. Но увы.. Слово такое смешное "увы" :)

И нужно без display none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первым делом убираете `position:absolute` у дочернего `ul`. Таким образом он станет под своим родителем. Далее его нужно спрятать, если вам `display none` не подходит, то можете применить свойство `height:0px;overflow:hidden;` а при наведение на родительский `li` применять свойство `height:auto;`

Comment: работает, но вот только позиционирование dropdown кривое из-за padding. Это можно как-то решить?

Comment: И было бы совсем круто если бы не нужно было писать -padding.

Comment: Ну в таком случае расположите под-меню левее с помощью position:relative;left:-15px;  и не забудьте убрать top:-9999px; иначе ваше подменю улетит вверх.

Comment: Тогда ещё вопрос - как в css лучше всего позиционировать? Вот например задав размеры li с помощью padding наблюдаются последствия с позиционированием дочерних элементов. И измени я значение padding, придется изменять и -15. Как правильно поступать в таких случаях?

Comment: Зависит от конкретной задачи, от того чего вам нужно добится этим свойством. К примеру примеру нужно padding для того что бы название пункта меню имело пространство, тогда конечно же padding лучше ставить элементу "a".